# When should I use/not use pooled and unpooled DB connections?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

When is it appropriate to use connection pooling and what happens when the maximum number of connections is reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not appropriate to use connection pooling if the time taken to execute the SQL query is much larger than the time to create a connection. If you use a connection pooling and the maximum number of connections is reached the next request is put on a pending while either a connection is returned into the pool or a timeout is reached.